# Download report file which is to be generated in to client side

Tags: c#, reporting, telerik-reporting

I am using the below code to create and download a Telerik report.

```
var reportName = "../api/Templates/Invoice.trdp";
var reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
var reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.UriReportSource()
{
 Uri = reportName
};
reportSource.Parameters.Add("ID", 3);
reportSource.Parameters.Add("Username", "demouser");
var deviceInfo = new System.Collections.Hashtable()
{
 {"DocumentTitle", "Annual Report" }
};
var result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", reportSource, deviceInfo);
if (!result.HasErrors)
{
 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(reportName, "pdf"), result.DocumentBytes);
}
}
```

Once I host it in a server, it creates the file in the server side. How can I download it into the client machine without creating any files in the server.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in generating the file on the server side and then giving the client a link to the file, as long as there is some task to delete the report at some point after the file has been downloaded.  Make sure the directory the file is generated in is temporary, and that the filenames cannot be guessed.

Comment: @Neil, Yes. you are correct. Currently I am using that approach. But I just want to know weather can I directly download it to the client side.

Comment: That last line: `result.DocumentBytes` is that a `Stream` or a `byte[]`, either way, that could be converted to an `IFileResult` and passed directly to the client.

Comment: @Neil I achieved the task by using a similar way as u suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by returning the file back to the client using the return type `HttpResponseMessage`

```
public HttpResponseMessage GenerateOrderReport(int orderID)
    {
        var reportName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAttachmentURLTemplate"];
        string activeDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAttachmentSaveLocation"];
        string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(activeDir, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAttachmentSaveFolder"]);
        var reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
        var reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.UriReportSource()
        {
            Uri = reportName
        };
        reportSource.Parameters.Add("OrderID", 141);
        reportSource.Parameters.Add("OrderMethodTypeID", 2);

        var deviceInfo = new System.Collections.Hashtable()
        {
            {"DocumentTitle", "Order Report" }
        };

        var result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", reportSource, deviceInfo);
        if (!result.HasErrors)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            string newFileName = "OrderReport.pdf";
            newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(newPath, newFileName);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fileStream.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
            HttpResponseMessage fileResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var stream = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Open);
            fileResult.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            fileResult.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            fileResult.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            fileResult.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = newFileName;
            return fileResult;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Report contains errors. " + result.Errors[0].Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are still writing a file (in fact the same file every time, so if 2 requests come in at the same time, one will overwrite the other). You could bypass the file writing by using a memory stream.